# Playing multiple audio files with same class or ID using forEach or for loop using JS

Tags: javascript, foreach

Im using this code:

HTML (TailwindCSS):

```
 <img src="https://static9.depositphotos.com/1049691/1080/i/450/depositphotos_10806368-stock-photo-fresh-apples.jpg" alt="" class="\>
```

JS:

```
function play() {
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.play();
}

function deny() {
var deny = document.getElementById("deny");
deny.play();

}

function give() {
```

var give = document.getElementById("give");
give.play();

```
}
```

My give and deny functions will only play 1 audio file and thats fine. Instead of making multiple codes or DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself), how do i avoid reusing this play block 20 different times and just simply use a for loop or forEach?

I tried using:

JS:

```
    function play() {
    let playAll = document.querySelectorAll('audio');playAll.forEach((item) => {item.onclick = ()    =>  play();
 )}
```

HTML:
Item 1:

```
<img src="https://static9.depositphotos.com/1049691/1080/i/450/depositphotos_10806368-stock-         photo-fresh-apples.jpg" alt="" class="\>

<audio id="audio" src="dist\\assets\\audio\\I Want Apple.mp3"\>\</audio\>
```

Item 2:

```
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/marshmallow-crispy-rice-treat-against-white-     background-picture-id453551221?k=20&m=453551221&s=612x612&w=0&h=Q4-w0zgUvkTx56cpkLTz9eUH2UbNRGqiQyND528pDn4=" alt="" class="\>

<audio id="audio" src="dist\\assets\\audio\\I want rice krispy.mp3"\>\</audio\>
```

Item 1 and Item 2 are both playing "I want apple" instead of looping through

Answer (score 0):

Call `play` on the current audio element itself.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(
    item => item.addEventListener('click', () => item.play()));
```

Comment: help me understand this a bit more. is document.querySelectorAll('audio') getting all the audio elements or is it grabbing all the classes with the name "audio"? Or am I putting this inside the function play () scope? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Steff86 It's getting all audio elements.

Comment: `function play() {
    document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach(
        item => item.addEventListener('click', () => item.play()));  
        console.log('It played? Y or N');
    
  }`


This grabs all the images and loops through them. but doesn't trigger the element to play the sound when clicked:

`<audio id="audio" src="dist\assets\audio\I Want Apple.mp3"></audio>`

Sorry, im having a hard time formatting the comment appropriately to where its understandable.